# Some questions of proof of Clifford Theorem in Hartshorne's AG book IV. 5.4.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Here is the statement of the theorem:

> **Theorem 5.4**. (Clifford). Let $D$ be an effective special divisor on the curve $X$. Then
> $$\dim|D|\leq\frac{1}{2}\deg(D).$$ Furthermore, equality occurs if and only if either $D=0$ or $D=K$ or $X$ is hyperelliptic and $D$ is a multiple of the unique $g_2^1$ on $X$.

Here special means $l(K-D)>0$ and $g_2^1$ means a linear system of dimension $1$ and degree $2$ (which induces a map $X\to\mathbb{P}^1$ of degree 2, that is, $X$ is hyperelliptic).

---

Here are my questions:

(i) In the first line of the proof, Hartshorne writes the following:

> If $D$ is effective and special, then $K-D$ is also effective...

Why $K-D$ is effective? We just know that $l(K-D)>0$, but this cannot imply $K-D>0$.

(ii) In the last paragraph of the proof, we let $D\neq0,K$ and $r:=\dim|D|=\frac{1}{2}\deg(D)$. Consider the linear system $|D|+(g-1-r)g_2^1$. It has degree $2g-2$ and dimension $\geq g-1$. But why does this imply that $|K|=|D|+(g-1-r)g_2^1$?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(i): You're right, depending on the choice of representation for $K$, it may not be the case that $K-D$ is effective. But $l(K-D)>0$ does imply that $K-D$ is linearly equivalent to an effective divisor $E$, and this is enough: we get a map $|D|\times |E|\to |D+E|$ satisfying the hypotheses of lemma IV.5.5, and then we may use the fact that $|E|=|K-D|$ as well as $|D+E|=|D+K-D|=|K|$, so we get the claimed map $|D|\times |K-D|\to |K|$ and can apply lemma IV.5.5 to it.

(ii): Suppose $E$ is a divisor so that $\deg E = 2g-2$ and $\dim |E| \geq g-1$. Then $l(E) \geq g$, and Riemman-Roch says $$l(E) - l(K-E) = 2g-2-g+1=g-1$$ which implies $l(K-E)\geq 1$. But $\deg K-E=0$, and we know that $l(K-E)\leq \deg(K-E)+1$ with equality iff $(K-E)\sim 0$ or $g=0$ (exercise IV.1.5, [proof here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4349503/proof-that-for-an-effective-divisor-ld-leq-deg-d-1/4349692#4349692)). Since $\Bbb P^1$ has no effective special divisors, it must be the case that $K-E\sim0$, or $K\sim E$.

Comment: Thank you very much! Now I know these clearly.

Comment: I find that here we get $\deg(K-E)=0$ and $l(K-E)>0$, so there must exists an effective divisor $F\sim K-E$. So $F\sim0$ implies $K\sim E$.